# Previously working Pi doesn't restart: ERROR 00000004

Tags: raspbian, boot, boot-issues

I am using my RaspberryPi 4 that's running Raspbian mainly for OpenMediaVault 5. There are various tutorials online that describe how I have done it. I don't know if I used [this one](https://linuxhint.com/raspberry_pi_open_media_vault/) at the time, but it seems to roughly reflect my process, which is to essentially flash the Raspbian image and then run these commands:

```
###### Install OMV Raspberry Pi ######

## change password ##
passwd

## change user to root ##
sudo su

## update Raspbian ##
apt update && apt upgrade -y

## delete network symlink ##
rm -f /etc/systemd/network/99-default.link

## reboot ##
reboot

## login & change user to root ##
sudo su

## install OMV 5 using install skript ##
wget -O - https://github.com/OpenMediaVault-Plugin-Developers/installScript/raw/master/install | sudo bash

## reboot after installation ##
reboot

## open Raspberry Pi's IP in Browser ##
http://raspberrypi.local
```

When I did it the first time, that setup worked for a few months, and then at one random reboot, it didn't come back up again. At the time I couldn't figure it out and ultimately ended up backing up some data and re-flashing the SD card.

Now, several months later it happened again, and I am kind of tired of setting everything up again without understanding the issue. What I noticed this time was that right before the reboot I updated and for some reason got the typical apt lock message:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock – open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

That's in fact the reason I decided to reboot. I then just saw this:

[image: output]

Is there maybe anything I can look for on the SD card to try and fix this? I am aware of a few forum posts online with the same issue, however I've never come across one that had a solution that is not re-flashing everything.

Comment: looks like the first partition of the SD card (the one you can read in ANY PC) is being corrupted

Comment: In a fixable way?

Comment: not sure - you fixed it once - given the right tools you can just re-image the boot partition

Comment: Yes I am aware it's fixable by re-flashing. My post is specifically about understanding what's wrong, what caused it, and how it can maybe be fixed without re-flashing :)

Comment: at a guess, faulty SD card - the only way to know is to buy another one

Comment: That's unlikely, as re-flashing fixed it last time.